# How to see which database Craft is currently connected to?

Tags: database

I was able to install Craft using a Vagrant/Homestead setup, but I can't seem to connect to the database I want. I set up my hosts file to point to a '.dev' address while working locally on my machine.

My **db.php** file seems to be set up ok:

```
return [
  '*' => [
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
  ],
  '.dev' => [
    'database' => 'dev',
    'user' => 'homestead',
    'password' => 'secret',
  ],
  '.org' => [
    'database' => 'prod',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '********',
  ],
];
```

When I ssh into my vagrant box and log into mysql, I can `SHOW DATABASES` and see:

```
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| dev                |
| prod               |
| homestead          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

I'm overwriting the dev, prod and homestead databases with a backedup .sql file, however when I visit my local '.dev' address, my Craft site doesn't appear to carrying over any of those changes.

Is there a way to see which database Craft is actually connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to at least see which environment from your multi-environment config that Craft is matching:

```
$craft = require 'path/to/craft/app/bootstrap.php';
echo $craft->config->get('server', ConfigFile::Db);
```

Comment: This returns "Class 'ConfigFile' not found" for me.